# Manually Setting the frame of MKOverlayView (or subview)

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I have a view that I am using as an overlay on a MKMapView (it uses OpenGL to draw).  For the drawing to be performed correctly, the frame of the glView needs to be exactly the same as the frame of the mapView.  I also cannot have the view just be on top of the map, because I want other annotations and overlays to be on top of it.

The way I have tried to do it is to create an MKOverlayView that's boundingMapRect = MKMapRectWorld.  I then add the glView as a subview to the overlayView and manually set the glView.frame = mapView.frame.  The problem is that the frame of the glView is using a different coordinate system than the mapView is.

The mapView's frame is in the coordinates that you would expect for a standard view (something like 0,0,320,250).  The glView's frame seems to be using MKMapPoints as its coordinate base.

So my idea was to do something like this in my MKOverlayView subclass...

```
glView.frame = [self rectForMapRect:[mapView visibleMapRect]];
```

This gives me a rect in the correct coordinates (something like 61612032.000000, 105586688.000000, 5275648.000000, 5685248.000000), but it is not perfectly alligned with the map. The y-direction is off and the zoom is sometimes wrong as well.

So my question would be this.

1. Is there a way to just set the frame of MKOverlayView (or one of its subviews) using normal screen coordinates?
2. Or is there another way that I could achieve the same thing that I am just missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert cgpoint into mkmappoint by using the mkoverlay method 
`- (MKMapPoint)mapPointForPoint:(CGPoint)point`

I hope it helps you

SOURCE: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKOverlayView/mapPointForPoint: